# Base64 partial encoding

Tags: split, base64, decode, encode

I have to encode in base64 an array of bytes (that is a byte stream of a Zipfile) but the array is too big. So I split the array in two parts, encode the first half, then the second one, and in the end I append the second part to the first part. The thing is that sometimes when i decode the result the zipfile seems to be corrupted.

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    while((len = fis.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
        baos.write(buffer);
    }

    byte[] bArray = baos.toByteArray();

    int bArrayLength = bArray.length;

    byte[] part1 = new byte[bArray.length / 2];
    byte[] part2 = new byte[ (bArrayLength%2 == 0) ? (bArray.length / 2) : (bArray.length / 2 + 1)];

    System.arraycopy(bArray, 0, part1, 0, part1.length);
    System.arraycopy(bArray, part1.length, part2, 0, part2.length);

    resultArray[0] = Base64.encodeBytes(part1);
    resultArray[1] = Base64.encodeBytes(part2);
```

What is the problem? Is that split that causes the issue?

Comment: Why don't you make a test: 1 (or 100) small file/byte array, encode it with split and without it, decode them and compare two results to source.

Comment: I did the test, compairing the two results i found that they are always different, but in most of the cases the final zip is not going to be corrupted, but in other cases yes, so I can't split the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably doesn't work because of *padding*. The Base64 algorithm pads its output with a == if its encoding results in a trailing group (of 24 bits) that contains only 1 byte, or = if it contains only 2 bytes. That means you cannot just add two encoded strings together and expect to get the correct result.

But how do you know the array is too big -- do you get an OutOfMemoryException?

You may try to split not exactly at the halfway point, but choose a different point until you no longer get a trailing = for that part.

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64.

Comment: Yeah it turned out that this was the case, and yes, I get an OutOfMemoryException, i'm thinking of doing the job using streams now..

Answer (score 0):

base 64 encoding reads 3 bytes and convert them to 4 bytes and if the text is not aligned to 3/4 factor there is a pad to be added so when you split the file there is 2 pads has been from the encoding process, and what you need to do to split it to two half's exactly where the pad finishes for every half decode them based on 4 bytes read /3 bytes output factor and then concatenate them once again, so you need to consider the size of every half after and before encoding for the process to work